# What is the name of the manga where main character summons a powerful being that turns out to be Spirit King?

Tags: story-identification, manga

Later on in the manga when mc accomplishes something and is invited to a noble party a noble girl around the same age challenges him to a spirit user duel with her earth spirit, but she starts early and reckless and mc saves her and the spirit recognizes the spirit king. Manga is in Black and white mostly.

Answer (score 1):

Moto-sekai ichii sub-chara ikusei nikki

mc is a game player and uses his summon card to summon Angolmois, the king of all spirits, in chapter 29. the encounter between mc and the noble with an earth spirit is after that.